# Change file "Birth date" for ext4 files?

Tags: linux, files, ext4, stat, touch

Is it possible to change a file "Birth date" (according to the `stat file` "Birth" field)?

I can change the modification/access time with `touch -t 200109110846 file`, but can't find the corresponding option for "Birth".

Comment: Which filesystem? There might be some fs-specific tool

Comment: @muru ext4.....

Comment: Birth date isn't accessible from userland.

Comment: @roaima why so?

Comment: Correction: `statx()` from kernel 4.11 onwards does expose `btime`.

Comment: It may be possible to do this for ext2/ext3/ext4 file systems with [`debugfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the last change time, the birth time isn’t externally controllable. On file systems which support it, the birth timestamp is set when a file is created, and never changes after that.

If you want to control it, you need to change the system’s notion of the current date and time, and create a new file.

Comment: .. or compile a custom kernel that exposes these inode fields to writing. wonder why noone seems to have released something like that..